# Make Meteor.methods secured from advanced users in the Console

Tags: security, meteor, methods, console

Say you have a Method in Meteor to remove a document:

```
Meteor.methods({

  discard_meeting({ meeting_id }) {
    Meetings.remove({ _id: meeting_id });
  },

});
```

If a user calls this method at the Console, they should be able to remove this element (if he knows the _id, maybe looking at the html... :)

What if, the app had a secret_key at the server that are added to every method, to prevent "advanced users" to mess with the data?

Like:

```
import { METHOD_TOKEN } from '/server/tokens.js';

Meteor.methods({

  discard_meeting({ token, meeting_id }) {
    if (token === METHOD_TOKEN) {
      Meetings.remove({ _id: meeting_id });
    }
  },

});
```

Do you think this could be a good idea?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

But then again someone can still access your method by finding your token with a brute force search. The correct way is in your method to check if your user is logged in and has the privilege to remove the meeting. Something like:

```
    meeting = Mettings.find({meetingId});

    if (this.userId != meeting.creator) {
      throw new Meteor.Error('unauthorized', 'You are not allowed to delete the meeting!');
    }
```

In addition you should validate the data you are passing to the method. An easy way to do that is by using [Validated Methods](https://guide.meteor.com/methods.html#validated-method). Have a look in the [Meteor Guide](https://guide.meteor.com/methods.html) to get a better understanding of how to write correct method definitions.

Comment: This is clear, but if the token is never exposed to the client (the value lives only on the server), how could it be finded?

Comment: By calling the method with all possible token values

Comment: "All possible values" is only practical for small tokens. If you use something like a SHA256 hash then a brute force attack will probably not be practical. You can also throttle method calls.